While Executing pipeline causing memory space issue
we have jenkins pipeline and we have server where docker is installed and jenkins agent is installed now we triggering some docker file execution in that server, what you do is you trigger a pipeline, pipeline will go to some server X and from there it will start executing docker files so till yesterday night it was working fine and after coming back to work today it started failing bacause of space issue but when we check the server space is pretty much free in the server but still it is saying server space issue so how we can troubleshoot it?Need someone help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
